# CodeIgniter htaccess www to non www and http to https

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, https

I have tried many things but failed. Something work for http to https and some for www to non www. But when I try modification for both http to https along with www to non www it broke my website.
Please help me in .htaccess modification for both rules
This the full of default .htaccess file

It successfully redirects http to https and www to non-www. but when I type http://www.xzy.com page show blank

```
# Case 1
# -------------------------------------------------------#
# RewriteEngine On
# DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
# -------------------------------------------------------#  

# Case 2
# -------------------------------------------------------#
# RewriteEngine on
# ExpiresActive On
# ExpiresDefault A2592000
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
# RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|public|assets|uploads|themes|install|backups|updates|asset|mob|robots\.txt|curl.php)
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
# -------------------------------------------------------#

# Case 3
# -------------------------------------------------------#
# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
# </IfModule>
# -------------------------------------------------------#

# Case 4
# -------------------------------------------------------#
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
# -------------------------------------------------------#

# Case 6 for SSL Hosting
# -------------------------------------------------------#
# RewriteEngine on
# ExpiresActive On
# ExpiresDefault A2592000
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
# RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|public|assets|uploads|themes|install|updates|asset|mob|robots\.txt)
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
# -------------------------------------------------------#

# case 5
# -------------------------------------------------------#
#RewriteEngine On
#DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
# -------------------------------------------------------#

# secure GIT files
RedirectMatch 404 /\.git

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
 ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
 mod_gzip_on Yes
 mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
 mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
 mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

It successfully redirects http to https and www to non-www. but when I type http://www.xzy.com page show blank

Comment: Could you please confirm once, if you want www in https url or not? Good that you have shown your htaccess file in your question, its good to show from which url(example/sample only) to which url(example/sample only) you want to redirect/rewrite for better understanding of question.

Comment: I don't have much info about redirect and rewrite different. I want to fix my URL Canonicalization issue regarding SEO. I want to redirect everything to https//mydomain.com to avoid a duplication issue

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Its only working for http to https and not working to redirect http://www and https://www to non-www

Comment: did you implement your ssl certificate properly??

Comment: Yes, my SSL is working perfectly. check here travesgo.com

Comment: I am also using Cloudflare for CDN where I have added a DNS record for www to non-www and enable Full SSL/TLS

Comment: Perfect its working perfect for redirect but it's not getting my website contact and 404 eror

Comment: did you put your base_url on config??

Comment: Here is code: $config['base_url'] = $root;

Comment: try $config['base_url']  = 'https://something.com/'

Comment: When I change this I have seen a 404 error on every page

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to solve your issue

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: this code also not working for me its also remove the http to https and www to non-www still the same.